# Constructible angle definition

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, geometric-construction

While studying a course on field theory, my prof gave the definition of constructible angle as

> An angle $\theta (0\leq\theta\leq2\pi)$ is said to be constructible, iff the length $\cos\theta$ is constructible.

After a some search in textbooks and reference books (and also on the internet), I found one more definition:

> An angle $\theta$ is said to be constructible if it is possible to construct two intersecting lines that form an angle of $\theta$

However for the the following definition looks more natural, but surprisingly it doesnt appear in any **standard textbook**

**Edit**

> An angle $\theta$ is said to be constructible, if it can be constructed using ruler and compass.

Is there something wrong with this definition? If so, can someone explain?

-- Mike

Comment: The last definition is circular and thus untenable.

Comment: OK, edited to remove the recursion. I felt the recursion was just the grammatical aberration.

Comment: It's still circular! And the other definitions are there to provide _explicit, separate_ characterisations of a constructible angle.

Comment: The definition using ruler and compass is the classical one, but to be effective you need to specify exactly how the ruler and compass are supposed to be used in the context of Euclidean plane geometry. After the Cartesian revolution in geometry, it became possible to convert those rules to algebraic ones.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel, can you please explain a bit more? I am not able to see how it is **still circular**...

Answer (score 3):

Contrary to some of the comments, I would not call the proposed "definition" of a constructible angle circular, but I *would* say it is useless for its avowed purpose.

When we use the word "constructible," we *do* need to say more specifically what we mean by it, since the choice of tools determines what we can construct. (Even the ancient Greeks classified constructions by which tools you used.) But once we decide we want compass-and-straightedge constructions, we say, "An object is said to be constructible if it can be constructed using straightedge and compass." It is now trivial to substitute "an angle $\theta$" for the more general "an object," but until we say what it means to construct an angle with ruler and compass, the definition is of little use.

Hence we see textbooks explain "constructible angle"
using a much more specific description of exactly what the results of such a construction would be.
(The two definitions given describe different constructed objects but can be seen to be equivalent, as you can easily get the object described in either definition from the object described in the other.)

Answer (score 0):

Formally, an angle is constructible by compass and straightedge if its cosine can be expressed as a finite combination of arithmetic operations and square root extractions. This is because the basic shapes formed by compass and straighedge are lines and circles, constructible points are intersections among lines and circles, and the equations describing these intersections are either linear or quadratic polynomial equations.

This is because if you construct an angle inside a circle (forming two radii), you can construct a line segment perpendicular to one of the rays that intersects with the circle at its intersection with the other ray. This segment and the two radii form a right triangle, and the cosine is the ratio of one of segments and the circle's radius.

It was proven by Pierre Wantzel that if an angle is a rational multiple of a right angle, it is only constructible if it is of the form $\frac {Qz}{2^nF}$, where $Q$ is the measure of a right angle, $z$ and $n$ are integers, $n>1$, and $F$ is the product of distinct Fermat primes.

(This implies that if $f$ is a Fermat prime, any angle is a rational multiple of a right angle can be $f$-sected if either its measure is of the form $\frac {Qz}{2^nG}$, and $G$ is the product of distinct Fermat primes excluding $f$, or else it is an $f$-multiple of a right angle divided by $2^nF$. Thus, the 60 degree angle can not be trisected by this method ($90*2/3=60$), but can be quintisected, 17-sected, 257-sected, and 65537-sected by this method. )